# MySQL table synchronization

Tags: mysql, synchronization

I have a server that constantly writes SQL queries it executes to a textfile. I want this textfile to be read by a second server, execute the queries there, and remove them from the textfile. This is done in an attempt to keep those 2 servers virtually synchronous with each other without changing existing code.

Comment: Maybe replication is the better solution? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/replication.html

Answer (score 2):

Try this one:
http://www.maatkit.org/doc/mk-table-sync.html

But I think that Native thing such as mysql replication should be preferred